# Add the user role to the jwt, laravel 5 jwt-auth

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I have a laravel 5 backend that sends an jwt-token as a json response on login with [jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth).

Now I would like to add the user role to the jwt token that laravel sends, I tried the following way:

**This is my current controller**

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\User;

class AuthenticateController extends Controller
{
    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        // grab credentials from the request
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        $user = User::where('email', '=', $credentials['email'])->first();
        $customClaims = ['role' => $user->role];

        try {
            // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
            if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials, $customClaims)) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
            return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
        }
        // all good so return the token
        return response()->json(compact('token'));
    }
}
?>
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this ?

Comment: JWT for php is bad documented. To make a simple login/logout system is painful! See my questions about it.

Comment: you can create a token from anything you like. it doesn't have to be a user or a set of permissions. https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Creating-Tokens#creating-a-token-based-on-anything-you-like So i think it's better to set this login on your model or repository and call it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently querying for the user twice, once using the email for the purpose of getting the role and the second within the `jwt::attempt()` method.I would suggest reducing the queries to just one but doing the authentication {Auth::attempt($credientials)} and then
passing the retrieved user  into   `JWT::fromUser()` method, along with the custom claim. so

```
JWT::fromUser($user,['role' => $user->role])
```

Comment: This link auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/quick-start solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's strange, specifying some *$customClaims* as second parameter for the *attempt()* method actually works for me.

However, have you tried to use the **JWTFactory** Facade? It lets you create every kind of token you want.

You can get more info here: [JWT-Auth Creating Tokens Page](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Creating-Tokens#creating-a-token-based-on-anything-you-like).

As the [installation guide suggests](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Installation), don't forget to add it as a Facade while installing JWT-Auth!

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there isn't a cleaner way in the current stable version of JWTAuth[0.5.9].

Take a look on the following issues [#89](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/89) [#108](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/pull/108)

As the author pointed out in his comments there will be improvements in his next release covering this issue. You can take a look on his develop branch.

Answer (score 0):

`JWT v1.0`'s documentation causes confusion. 
Add this method to your user model, so you can add custom claims when you authenticate users:

```
public function getJWTCustomClaims()
{

        return = [
            'type' => 'driver',
            'id' => $this->driver->id
        ];
}
```